# JCache with Oracle Coherence

Tags: ehcache, oracle-coherence, jcache

Oracle Coherence states that it is "JCache-compliant".  How can I take my code written against [JSR-107](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107), specifically the [ehcache-jcache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/jsr107.html) jar, and run it against Oracle Coherence?

Answer (score 3):

Final JCache APIs are expected to be released in summer/fall 2013. Then you can expect to see those final APIs supported in Coherence.

Update (14 February 2014) - As soon as we check off some legal check-boxes, the APIs & RI & TCK are all ready to be submitted for approval, and the next version of Coherence (version 12.1.3) will include & support the final APIs.

Update (11 July 2014) - The JCache standard is done and out, and Coherence now officially supports the JCache standard; see the documentation at: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/coherence/develop-applications/jcache_part.htm

*For the sake of full disclosure, I work at Oracle. The opinions and views expressed in this post are my own, and do not necessarily reflect the opinions or views of my employer.*

Comment: will coherence work with JCacheCacheManager of spring?

Answer (score 1):

The ehcache-jcache jar is a specific implementation of JSR-107. Coherence is not binary compatible with that implementation. Coherence is compliant with the interfaces specified in JSR-107 but provides its own implementation.

Coherence offers a huge number of features beyond JSR-107, so it would be overkill to use it just for JSR-107.