# Spring cache with Oracle Coherence

Tags: java, spring, caching, oracle-coherence

I have to get a Spring Cache interface implementation that works with Coherence. As far as I could research, there is not such an implementation provided by Spring or Coherence (As there is for ehcache, i.e.). So, I had to make my own which I paste at the bottom. It works well on the integration tests, but I would like to know if someone has faced a similar problem, and has any suggestion or correction to this code.

```
import com.tangosol.net.CacheFactory;
import com.tangosol.net.NamedCache;

public class MyCoherenceCache implements Cache {
    private final NamedCache cache;

    private static int instanceCounter = 0;

    @Override
    public synchronized void clear() {
        cache.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void evict(Object object) {
        cache.remove(object);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized ValueWrapper get(Object key) {
        if (cache.get(key) == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return new SimpleValueWrapper(cache.get(key));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return cache.getCacheName();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNativeCache() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error: Unimplemented method!");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void put(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
        cache.put(arg0, arg1);

    }

    MyCoherenceCache(String cacheName) {
        super();
        instanceCounter++;
        cache = CacheFactory.getCache(cacheName);
    }

    public static int getInstanceCounter() {
        return instanceCounter;
    }

}
```

Comment: what kind of problems are you facing? Exceptions?

Comment: Actually, I'm not facing any problems. I just would like to know if the code could be improved. Or if some potential problems could be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You want to take a look at JSR-107 (also known as JCache) which is the formal equivalent Spring's own Caching annotations, [added in Spring v3.1](https://spring.io/blog/2014/04/14/cache-abstraction-jcache-jsr-107-annotations-support).  Fully certified JCache support should be [in the next release of Oracle Coherence (v12.1.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17089132/376962)

Comment: Yup! It's out! See: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/coherence/develop-applications/jcache_part.htm